# Reading from a big table

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I want to read data from a table (or view) on SQL server 2008R2 using PHP 5.4.24 and freetds 0.91.
In PHP, I write:

```
$ret = mssql_query( 'SELECT * FROM mytable', $Conn ) ;
```

Then I read rows one at a time, process them, all is ok. Except, when the table is really big, then I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4625408 bytes)
in /home/prove/test.php on line 43
```

The error happens in the mssql_query(), so it does not matter how I query.

Altering the query to return less rows or less columns is not viable, because I must read a lot of data from many tables in a limited time.

What can I do to convince PHP to read in memory one row at a time, or a reasonable number at a time?

Comment: How many rows are we talking about and how much data is in each row?

Comment: Having indexes may help, if you're not already using those.

Comment: Do you really need everything from the table? Perhaps you could consider splitting it into small tables.

Comment: I have no control on the database server, and I cannot read some lines/columns every time because the tables involved are many and I would like to keep the code simple.

Comment: Maybe unbuffered queries will help: PDO : details: [PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_DYNAMIC: Creates a server-side (unbuffered) dynamic cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628176%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). OR: PHP Manual :[function.sqlsrv-query.](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php)

Comment: Table has 5 millions row, each some hundred bytes total size.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @James in the Question comments, if you need to read a table so big it exhausts your memory to stash the results before even handing back to PHP, it probably just means you need to figure out a better way. However, here is a possible solution (untested and I've only used MSSQL a couple of times; but if not perfect, I tried my best):

```
$ret = mssql_query( 'SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRows FROM mytable', $Conn);
$row = mssql_fetch_row($ret);

$offset    = 0;
$increment = 50;
while ($offset < $row['TotalRows'])
{
    $ret_2 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Id ASC OFFSET {$offset} ROWS FETCH NEXT {$increment} ROWS ONLY", $Conn);

    //
    // loop over those 50 rows, do your thing...
    //

    $offset += $increment;
}

//
// there will probably be a remainder, so you'll have to account for that in the post-iteration; probably making the interior loop a function or method would be wise.
//
```

Comment: And thinking about it, if the structure is badly designed in the first place, then a hack (albeit also a fantastic fix) would be as @Fred-ii- suggested - indexes if none already exist. On a poorly designed table, it can make an entire world of difference, though the query would need to be amended to use the index more efficiently.